# Is there an efficient way to get the length of a global static string in C?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char doc_type_tag[] = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";


int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

I  have a global string, and I realize `sizeof (doc_type_tag) / sizeof (doc_type_tag[0]);` is not valid.

Is there any other way other than strlen?

Comment: If you make it `static const char[] doc_type_tag = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"` instead, which you should, as it saves a pointer, you can use `sizeof`, noting that it will include the trailing null. NB `static` is not global.

Comment: Are you sure? I get "expected a ;"

Comment: Don't tell me you removed the trailing `;` from the declaration.

Comment: Maybe it should be `static const char doc_type_tag[] = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"`. I haven't coded C in a long time, I'm probably thinking in Java still.

Comment: @user207421 I edited the op, this is literally what's in my c file. I'm using visual studio, if that matters.

Comment: @user207421 That's it!

Comment: Most compilers (at least gcc and clang) will optimise the `strlen` if they are confident the variable won't change. `static const char* x = "foo";` works. So does `const char* const x = "foo";` And of course local symbols are much easier to optimise, since they have no linkage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm puzzled by your assertion:

> I realize `sizeof (doc_type_tag) / sizeof (doc_type_tag[0]);` is not valid.

Given that the variable has file scope but its visibility is restricted to this file, the array definition is fully visible and the size is defined in full.

The rules would be a bit different if there were multiple source files and this file had `extern char doc_type_tag[];` and not the actual array definition — with the initialization.

But with the array definition there, the `sizeof` expression works fine.  It also works for `char doc_type_tag[] = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"` because the complete array definition is visible.

Of course, you also have to fix the position of the array brackets.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char doc_type_tag[] = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
enum { DOC_TYPE_TAG_SZ = sizeof(doc_type_tag) / sizeof(doc_type_tag[0]) };

const char html_tag[] = "<html>";
enum { HTML_TAG_SZ = sizeof(html_tag) / sizeof(html_tag[0]) };

int main(void)
{
    size_t sz_doc_type_tag = sizeof(doc_type_tag) / sizeof(doc_type_tag[0]);
    printf("%zu (%d) [%s]\n", sz_doc_type_tag, DOC_TYPE_TAG_SZ, doc_type_tag);
    size_t sz_html_tag = sizeof(html_tag) / sizeof(html_tag[0]);
    printf("%zu (%d) [%s]\n", sz_html_tag, HTML_TAG_SZ, html_tag);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the enumeration values are of type `int` and not `size_t`, hence the different conversion specifications.

#### Output:

```
17 (17) [<!DOCTYPE html>
]
7 (7) [<html>]
```

#### Pointers

If the declaration was:

```
 static const char *doc_type_tag = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
```

then we'd be in a very different discussion — there isn't a way to find out the length of the string pointed at by `doc_type_tag` except by using `strlen()` or something equivalent to it, not least because although what it points at when the program starts is clear enough, it could be reassigned to point somewhere else by the time its value is used.  And the `sizeof(doc_type_tag) / sizeof(doc_type_tag[0])` expression would usually evaluate to `8` (or `4` if you're using a 32-bit compilation), because that's the size of the pointer.  Pointers are not arrays, especially in the context of `sizeof`.

#### Main program: `as31.c`

Here's a multi-file variation on the code above:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "xml.h"

static const char doc_type_tag[] = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
enum { DOC_TYPE_TAG_SZ = sizeof(doc_type_tag) / sizeof(doc_type_tag[0]) };

const char html_tag[] = "<html>";
enum { HTML_TAG_SZ = sizeof(html_tag) / sizeof(html_tag[0]) };

int main(void)
{
    size_t sz_doc_type_tag = sizeof(doc_type_tag) / sizeof(doc_type_tag[0]);
    printf("%zu (%d) [%s]\n", sz_doc_type_tag, DOC_TYPE_TAG_SZ, doc_type_tag);
    size_t sz_html_tag = sizeof(html_tag) / sizeof(html_tag[0]);
    printf("%zu (%d) [%s]\n", sz_html_tag, HTML_TAG_SZ, html_tag);
    size_t sz_xml_decl_tag = sizeof(xml_decl_tag) / sizeof(xml_decl_tag[0]);
    printf("%zu (%d) [%s]\n", sz_xml_decl_tag, XML_DECL_TAG_SZ, xml_decl_tag);

    //size_t sz_pqr_tag = sizeof(pqr_tag) / sizeof(pqr_tag[0]);
    //enum { PQR_TAG_SZ = sizeof(pqr_tag) / sizeof(pqr_tag[0]) };

    printf("%zu [%s]\n", strlen(pqr_tag) + 1, pqr_tag);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `sizeof` games simply don't work on `pqr_tag`, declared in `xml.h` and defined in `xml.c`.  (I also removed the newline from the `doc_type_tag` initializer.)

#### Header file: `xml.h`

```c
extern char xml_decl_tag[56];
enum { XML_DECL_TAG_SZ = sizeof(xml_decl_tag) / sizeof(xml_decl_tag[0]) };

extern char pqr_tag[];
```

#### Definition file: `xml.c`

```c
char xml_decl_tag[56] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";

char pqr_tag[] = "<another tag>";
```

#### Output

```
16 (16) [<!DOCTYPE html>]
7 (7) [<html>]
56 (56) [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>]
14 [<another tag>]
```

Comment: My mistake, originally it was 
```static const char* doc_type_tag = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";```

Comment: That would give a different result — yes.  You'd probably get the result `8` from the `sizeof` expressions (`4` if you're using a 32-bit compilation).

Answer (score 0):

- In case of an array `const char doc_type_tag[] = "..."`:

  ```
  sizeof (doc_type_tag) / sizeof (doc_type_tag[0])       // size of array
  (sizeof (doc_type_tag) / sizeof (doc_type_tag[0]) - 1) // string length
  ```
- In case of a pointer `char* doc_type_tag = "..."`:

  ```
  #define INITIALIZER "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
  const char* doc_type_tag = INITIALIZER;
  ...
  sizeof(INITIALIZER)       // size of array
  (sizeof(INITIALIZER) - 1) // string length
  ```